# How can i plot the predicted value vs. actual value?

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, linear-regression

im trying to make a linear regression Model using Feed Forward neural network.
The following picture shows the head of the dataset including 188232 rows and 10 Columns, which the last column (curvature) is the Label and the first 9 Columns are Features.
[head of the dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndmOv.png)

There is no null-values and all of values are in range (-0.2,1) so I don't need to scale the values.
The following Part shows my python code.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
df = pd.read_csv('/content/dataset.csv')
vf = df.drop('curvature',axis=1) #Volume_frac ----> Features
curv = df['curvature']           #Curv ----> Label
TargetVariable=['Curvature']
Predictors=['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5', 'C6', 'C7', 'C8', 'C9']
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
vf_train_1 , vf_test , curv_train_1 , curv_test =train_test_split(vf , curv , test_size = 0.2)
vf_train , vf_val , curv_train , curv_val = train_test_split(vf_train_1 , curv_train_1 ,test_size = 0.1)
model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(100,activation = 'relu', input_dim = vf.shape[1]))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1,activation = 'linear'))
model.compile(loss = 'mean_squared_error', optimizer= 'adam', metrics= ['mse'])
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import History
history = History()
r = model.fit(vf_train,curv_train, validation_data = (vf_val, curv_val), batch_size= 45, epochs= 400, verbose = 1)

# To print the loss on both the training and validation data, use the following code segment:
plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('Accuracy')
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'validation'], loc='upper right')
plt.show()

#  We will also print the mean squared error to further verify this claim. To plot the mse, use the following code segment:
plt.plot(history.history['mse'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_mse'])
plt.title('mean squared error')
plt.ylabel('mse')
plt.xlabel('epochs')
plt.legend(['train' , 'validation'] , loc = 'upper right')
plt.show()

model_test_loss , model_test_mse = model1.evaluate(vf_test , curv_test , batch_size=45 , verbose=1)
print(f'model test_loss: {model_test_loss}')
print(f'model test_mse: {model_test_mse}')

# Generating Predictions on testing data
curv_pred=model.predict(vf_test)
TestingData=pd.DataFrame(data=vf_test, columns=Predictors)
TestingData['curvature']=curv_test
TestingData['Predicted curvature']=curv_pred
TestingData.head()


from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error,r2_score,mean_squared_error

#Mean absolute error
MAE = mean_absolute_error(TestingData['curvature'] , TestingData['Predicted curvature'])
TestingData['MAE'] = MAE
print(f'MAE:  {mean_absolute_error(curv_test, curv_pred)}' )

#r2 
R2 = r2_score(TestingData['curvature'] , TestingData['Predicted curvature'])
TestingData['R2'] = R2
print(f'R2-score  {r2_score(curv_pred , curv_test)} ')

#Mean squared error
MSE = mean_squared_error(TestingData['curvature'] , TestingData['Predicted curvature'])
TestingData['MSE'] = MSE
print(f'MSE:   {mean_squared_error(curv_test, curv_pred)}' )


TestingData.head()
```

I get the following metrics and loss according to my python code:

MAE:  0.005412364827309889

R2-score:  0.5829957539831627

MSE:   5.2291261382808895e-05

Now, im trying to have a plot for actual and predicted value like the following plot:

[the plot that i want to have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgTu2.jpg)
which comes from a matlab code according to This Problem.

but I can't make such a plot in python and i can get the following plot with following code segment:
[it is the plot,that i can get from my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGov9.png)

```
plt.scatter(curv_test, curv_pred)
plt.xlabel("curvature")
plt.ylabel("predicted curvature")
plt.title("curvature vs Predicted curvature")
plt.show()
```

How can i have a plot like that in matlab?
Is there any other Problems in my code?

Comment: The code for your plot looks right and your plot is consistent with the accuracy of your prediction (R2 = 0.58), so I do not think there is anything wrong with your plot. Is your question about how to improve the accuracy of your model? It is off-topic here and better asked for example here: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Comment: no, i want to know, how can i get a plot like the plot in matlab, that i attched.

Comment: I think you need to be more specific as to what features of the plot you are trying to emulate. is it the blue diagonal line? The legend? The title? Does you r question have anything to do at all with the code that fits your network? I suggest you edit your question and reword accordingly. And please read and follow the guidelines here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example